# How to make a patchy cloud layer?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics, photorealism

I want to make a cloud layer like shown in this image (where parts of it are empty patches).

[image]

I tried doing this by applying a volume scatter shader to a cube and then controlling the density with a have texture but it outputted as such :
[image]

I need this to look realistic, how do I achieve it?
I tried applying the method of a tutorial by [BlenderGuru](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/how-to-make-clouds-with-cycles), but could not get it to look patchy.

This is my setup:

[image]

Comment: Clouds in a volume cube are quite hard actually. May need particles and multiple volumes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put a color ramp in front of the multiply node to crush the noise node input into something workable with a color mix.

[image]

Comment: What did you attach the normal input to?

Comment: Im assuming you mean the VECTOR input. Vector is attached to the mapping node. if you have the node wrangler addon active, press CTRL+T while having a texture node selected, it auto-inserts them. This isnt anything thats necessary though since the procedural nodes automatically assume generated mapping anyways. I just did it out of habit.